# Displaying random text

Tags: php

http://www.uw-team.org/hm3next/skrypty/szukaj.php?name=asd

Refresh several times to see what it is doing.

And how to do something like that? I think that it is something with rand, but I can't really do it.

Comment: Please provide a better explanation, along with some code

Comment: Demanding fast reply warrants a downvote in my opinion. We are not tech support, we are volunteers looking to learn and help people. "I can't really do it" - sure you can, show us what you've tried. I get the feeling you haven't yet. And besides, on SO replies are very fast already.

Comment: Good luck with that attitude :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I understand your poorly asked question, something like this is what you're looking for:

```
$messages = array(
    'This is the first message',
    'This is the second message',
    'This is the third message'
);

echo $messages[rand(0, count($messages) - 1)];
```

Answer (score -1):

Yeah you are correct using random and array we can get this output...

Comment: This is not a real answer.